# Yii2 set MySQL user for first time migration table creation?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, migration

My issue has to do with the automated creation of the `migration` history table when first executing `yii migrate/up --interactive=0`.
I was able to override the database access credentials for the migrations themselves. (see example below)

For my web application, I have a user `default` that has the following `GRANT`s: `SELECT, INSERT`
For migrations, I want to use my `admin` user who has additional `GRANT`s for `DDL`.

When executing the migration `Yii2` wants to create a `migration` table with the `default` user which leads to a `permission denied` error.

How can I set the database user for the `migration` table creation?

My migration script:

```
<?php

use yii\db\Migration;

/**
 * Handles adding columns to table `{{%Tablename}}`.
 */
class m210907_145507_add_json_column_to_Tablename_table extends Migration
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->db = new \yii\db\Connection([
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=mysql;dbname=dbname',
            'username' => 'admin',
            'password' => 'itasecrettoeverybody',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'enableSchemaCache' => true,
            'schemaCacheDuration' => 60,
            'schemaCache' => 'cache',
        ]);
        parent::init();
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function safeUp()
    {
        $this->addColumn('{{%Tablename}}', 'json', $this->json());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function safeDown()
    {
        $this->dropColumn('{{%Tablename}}', 'json');
    }
}
```

The error:

```
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.43)

Creating migration history table "migration"...
Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 CREATE command denied to user 'default'@'172.27.0.4' for table 'migration'
The SQL being executed was: CREATE TABLE `migration` (
        `version` varchar(180) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        `apply_time` int(11)
)'

in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php:678

Error Info:
Array
(
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 1142
    [2] => CREATE command denied to user 'default'@'172.27.0.4' for table 'migration'
)

Caused by: Exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 CREATE command denied to user 'default'@'172.27.0.4' for table 'migration''

in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php:1302

Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(1302): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(1102): yii\db\Command->internalExecute()
#2 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/MigrateController.php(273): yii\db\Command->execute()
#3 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/MigrateController.php(212): yii\console\controllers\MigrateController->createMigrationHistoryTable()
#4 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(908): yii\console\controllers\MigrateController->getMigrationHistory()
#5 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(183): yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->getNewMigrations()
#6 [internal function]: yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->actionUp()
#7 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array()
#8 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(181): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams()
#9 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(184): yii\base\Controller->runAction()
#10 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(534): yii\console\Controller->runAction()
#11 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(181): yii\base\Module->runAction()
#12 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(148): yii\console\Application->runAction()
#13 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): yii\console\Application->handleRequest()
#14 /app/yii(20): yii\base\Application->run()
#15 {main}
```

Comment: Double check privileges, issue with db user i guess

Comment: @InsaneSkull as stated in the post, my problem is connected to not being able to switch to the user with the right permissions when executing the script. so the privileges are correct only the user selection in the `yii migrate/up --interactive=0` is the issue when there is no existing `migration` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations are run from console.

That means, the `console.php` config file is loaded instead of your `main.php` config. So one way, that would also affect any other console commands you might have, would be to change the `db` configuration in the `components` section of the `console` config.

`config\console.php`:

```
<?php

$config = [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => [], // PLACE HERE CUSTOM ADMIN CREDENTIALS
        // ...
    ],
    
];
```

Now your migrations will be run with the credentials defined in the console config.

If by chance you have other console commands that modify data in the database and you don't want to change their user too, then you could add another DB component and call it "dbAdmin" with the admin credentials.

```
<?php

$config = [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => [], // REGULAR DB connection
        'dbAdmin' => [], // PLACE HERE CUSTOM ADMIN CREDENTIALS
        // ...
    ],
    
];
```

And then check:

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-migrations#using-command-line-options

To specify what db connection to use when running the migrations.

```
yii migrate --db=dbAdmin
```